# Send entire folder via FTP from Android

Tags: android, ftp, directory, send

With my android app I'll be able to take a lot of pictures. I don't know a complete number of pics. So I want to send via FTP the entire folder with pics.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I would archive/compress (zip) it first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compress files first in to one file and then send. Here is a tutorial for compressing:  [Zipping Files in Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29).

Comment: Page link you provided is broken.. btw, when u copy paste a link it works, You need to edit your answer with proper hyperlink